# iOS 8.1 UITableview Background Colour always white

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

So I've tested this in iOS 7.1 and it works fine. I'm setting the background colour to clear on my tableview using the lines below.

```
    self.tableview = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableview.delegate = self;
    self.tableview.dataSource = self;
    self.tableview.backgroundView = nil;
    self.tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self addSubview:self.tableview];
```

I'm also setting the tableFooterView to a new view to hide any left over unused cells using.

```
self.tableview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

This works beautifully on iOS 7 but in iOS 8 I'm left with a white background colour for the space under the tableview. The superview the tableview sits inside also has a background colour of clear. Any ideas?

Added images below - I've had to obscure the client name

Working on iOS 7
[image: Working on iOS 7]

Not working on iOS 8.1[image]

Comment: What colour do you want it to have?

Comment: But what does that mean? You ain't gonna see the inner workings of the iPhone no matter how transparent you set it. Where the white is... what should be there instead?

Comment: I have a tableview that swipes in from the side, when there's not enough content for the number of cells to reach the bottom of the screen you should be able to see the background view of the original view.

Comment: Ah, how are you swiping it in from the side? Is it a modal transition to a new view controller that contains the table view?

Comment: No I'm animating a view constraint.

Comment: Try setting... `self.tableview.backgroundView = [UIView new];` and then also set the background colour to be clear.

Comment: That didn't work and won't work as Apple's documentations states "You must set this property to nil to set the background color of the table view" for the backgroundView property. Like I said works perfectly in iOS 7 and it's something I've done a thousand times before it's just not working today after updating my iPad to iOS 8.1 :(

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. I've used that in the past, lol. OK, we're going to need more information then. Screen shot of the storyboard/nib or more code of where you're creating the tableview. Also... could it be the background colour of the cells rather than the tableView?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some pretty pictures - I've had to obscure the client name hence the other random white boxes where I've cut their logo/name out of the image

Comment: Hmm... try setting.. `self.tableview.tableFooterView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: Still nothing such a frustrating little bug :/

Comment: I have a feeling it's something to do with that footer view. What happens if you try to set a different color. [UIColor redColor] for instance. Just to debug which code is having an effect (if it is having an effect at all).

Comment: Also, in your code you are creating the tableview with a frame equal to self.bounds. Then adding it to self. Are you sure that it's not the background color of self that is showing and not the tableview at all.

Comment: It's definitely not the superview background colour, hence why it works on iOS 7. Setting the background colour of the footer view only works if I add a frame to the footer, weirdly I can set it to any other colour except clear.

Comment: Or forget the breakpoint. When the table is on screen goto Debug - View Debugging - Capture View Hierarchy.

Comment: Wow that crashes my Xcode everytime I try, thank Apple :p

Comment: Are you on Xcode 6.1? And are you running on device or simulator?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Fogmeister that new view debugging is cool. I've managed to make a work around by simplifying my view heirachy. Rather than adding a tableview as a subview I'm using a uitableview as the base and it seems to work. No idea why but it works on iOS 7 and iOS 8

Answer (score 4):

Apple document says

*... In iOS 7, cells have a white background by default; in earlier versions of iOS, cells inherit the background color of the enclosing table view. If you want to change the background color of a cell, do so in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of your table view delegate.*

You might need to use willDisplayCell UITableView delegate method to have a transparent background for your table view .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cellforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
      [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: Holy Mother of God! iOS 8 will drive me nuts. This solution MUST be used, even with table cell color defined via Storyboard. I put "black" EVERYWHERE (Table, Cell, Content View, BG, FG, Tint...) and I still got white background (mainly on disclosure indicators). I add those lines to my UITableViewController and it worked. Seriously... Apple is dying after Jobs' death.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is what worked (I am using a custom `UITableViewCell` in its own XIB):

- Set the cell's content view background to clear color in IB.
- Set the cell's background to clear color in IB.
- Set the table view's background color to `UIColor.clearColor()` **programatically in viewDidLoad**. Doing it in the Storyboard doesn't work.